# Using Javascript to get the contents of a remote file when cross domain communication is allowed

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am working on a firefox extension. I am using javascript to make a remote request to get the file contents of a remote file. This is possible because firefox extensions allow cross-domain communication. So if cross domain communication is allowed, and I want the contents of a file named picture.png at URL www.xxx.com/picture.png. Is all I have to do is to send a GET request to that URL and response.text would be the file content?

Comment: Yes I did and I get back something but I am not sure if this is really the real file contents. response.text stores plain text of the response object while images/pdfs etc have non plain text characters. Also the response.text size is not identical to the real file size so I am suspicious

Comment: be sure to specify the appropriate content type in your `GET` request. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)

Comment: Also, it depends on what you want to do with the file content. If it really is a .png file the contents will be binary data. Do you just want to store the file locally? Examine the contents for metadata? The mind boggles.

Comment: I basically want to send the file contents back as an HTTP body for a new request to a different URL

Comment: I am also using firefox SDK which is really limiting

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to figure out how to read and then pass on an image to a separate request, why not use an [HTTP Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads#HTTP_Observers) to [redirect from the original URL to the one you want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpChannel#redirectTo%28%29)?